# How do I set Information on a pre existing metafield on Shopify using the python Shopify API

Tags: python, shopify, shopify-api

Hello Im trying to set the Metafields on a newly created Product to a certain value.
These Metafields are Metafields that I created on shopify myself and want to set to a certain value.
I tried to access the meta fields multiple times but Shopify seems to ignore it (no Error message, it just doesn't do anything). Also, the Documentation on the Shopify API for a beginner is not great. It would be nice if someone could provide me with something better. This is what I have done (The Init of the Session I left out of the Code snippet)

```
product = shopify.Product()
variant = shopify.Variant()
variant.price = 1000
variant.sku = "123"
variant.weight = 20
variant.unit = "kg"
product.title = "New product"
product.body_html = "Test description"
product.status = "draft"
product.variants = [variant]
product.metafields_global_title_tag = "product SEO title"
product.metafields_global_description_tag = " Meta description"
product.save()
product.add_metafield(shopify.Metafield({"key": "name_of_metafield", "value": "Testvalue", "type": multiline_text_field", "namespace": "global"}))
product.save()
```

I would have expected that the Metafield with the name `name_of_metafield` would have been set to the value `Testvalue`.

Is someone here that could help me? Like I said the docs are not really beginner friendly and I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All metafield information must match definition. In your example namespace looks suspicious - shouldn't it be "custom"?

I struggled because I used incorrect type. The metafield was defined as single_line_text_field, but I was trying to set the value giving "string" as the type. It was saving it as a separate metafield, but was not setting the values I needed.

To make sure you're using correct values set up a value in the UI and read it.

```
metafields=product.metafields()
```

The code that set the values for me:

```
product.add_metafield(shopify.Metafield({
    'namespace':"custom",
    'key':"old_sku",
    'value':old_sku,
    'type':"single_line_text_field"
}))
product.save()
```